# Detect directory with ObjectiveDropboxOfficial (Dropbox V2 API)

Tags: dropbox-api, swiftydropbox

How can you tell if the metadata for a "file" is a directory or file?

I'm using the new V2 dropbox API for Objective-C. I don't see any way to distinguish between a file and directory. I'm expecting a `.isDirectory` call similar to what was available in V1 of the API.

Is this API available in the Swift version of the API?

The following code lists all files and directories at the given path. (simplified, as it is ignoring "more files")

```
- (void)loadMetadataForPath:(NSString*)path
{
    [[self.dbUserClient.filesRoutes listFolder:path ] setResponseBlock:^(DBFILESListFolderResult * _Nullable result, DBFILESListFolderError * _Nullable routeError, DBRequestError * _Nullable networkError)
     {
         NSArray<DBFILESMetadata*>   *entries = result.entries;
         NSString                    *cursor  = result.cursor;
         BOOL                         hasMore = result.hasMore.boolValue;

         for (DBFILESMetadata *fileMetadata in entries)
         {
             // How do I test if this file is a directory?
//             BOOL isDirectory = fileMetadata.isDirectory;

             NSLog(@"Dropbox filename = %@", fileMetadata.name);
         }

         // Ingoring more files for simplicity
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isKindOfClass` to detect the type of the entry. There's [an example in the readme in the `printEntries` method here](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c#rpc-style-request).

Comment: I missed that in the example as part of the docs. Thanks. It wasn't in their sample DBRoulette app, or as a direct part of the API documentation. I think I'll try to request an API enhancement for an `isDirectory` call, as that is much clearer IMO and code completion will find it.